# Binary Search won't operate correctly

Tags: java, search, binary-search

I am writing a multi search algorithm for my dynamic array class, and with my implementation attempt of a binary search, but my program won't set the value of my integer `mid` properly.

Here is the code for the method:

```
public static boolean search(int[] array, int value) {
    int first = 0, last = array.length - 1, mid = ((first + last) / array.length);
    System.out.println(first + " - " + mid + " - " + last);
    while(true) {
        System.out.println(first + " - " + mid + " - " + last);
        if (value == array[mid]) {return true;}
        if (first == last || mid == last || mid == first) {return false;}

        if (value > array[mid]) {
            first = mid;
            mid = (first + last) / (last + 1);
        }
        if (value < array[mid]) {
            last = mid;
            mid = (first + last) / (last + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(first + " - " + mid + " - " + last);
    }
}
```

I ran the program with hundreds of tests, however, the value of mid is always 0 (the output is `0 - 0 - 111725` or `0 - 0 - 127` or `0 - 0 - 15`).
All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a [minimal but complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  It shouldn't be that much more effort for you, but that will allow us to simply copy-paste the code and run it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program?  I suspect that you would quickly be able to pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: @sstan There you go, all I added was the method footprint.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried that, however it showed me that something was wrong with my assignment of `mid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your array is ***ascending order*** order:

```
public static boolean search(int[] array, int value) {
    int first = 0, last = array.length - 1, mid = ((first + last) / 2); //Divide by 2
    System.out.println(first + " - " + mid + " - " + last);
    while(true) {
        System.out.println(first + " - " + mid + " - " + last);
        if (value == array[mid]) {return true;}
        if (first == last || mid == last || mid == first) {return false;}

        if (value > array[mid]) {
            first = mid;
            mid = (last + first) / 2; //Divide by 2
        }
        if (value < array[mid]) {
            last = mid;
            mid = (first + last) / 2; //Divide by 2
        }
        System.out.println(first + " - " + mid + " - " + last);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean "ascending order", not "little-endian" order.  "Little-endian" or "big-endian" refer specifically to which order the bytes that make up an integer (or other value) appear; big-endian means that the high-order byte is first and the low-order byte is last, little-endian is the reverse order.  Don't use the terms for anything else--it's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't:

```
mid = ((first + last) / array.length)
```

... actually be something like this

```
mid = ((first + last) / 2)
```

... instead to allow you to get the `mid`?

To get the middle between 2 values, you need to add both values ***and divide by 2***.